# MVC2 Anti-ForgeryToken help

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, session-timeout, antiforgerytoken, machinekey

I have applied an antiforgerytoken to my POST actions within my app.  When the session times out I am getting an "A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid" error.  I have added a machineKey to the web.config but this hasn't solved the problem.  Is there anything I need to do to force the token to use the machinekey?

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Seems like the login page is maybe caching the token?